# Refresh weirdness for jQuery in Internet Explorer with Dev. tools

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have developed a Joomla module, but my question is in regards to Internet Explorer...

Here is the URL: http://j25.wasen.net/index.php/news

To the right on this page you will see a list of files I call the "Simple File Lister". If you hover your mouse above files there should be a "tooltip" showing the whole filename and if you click an image a FancyBox should open.

This works fine in Chrome, Opera, Safari but not directly in Internet Exporer. I have tested this on three different Windows installs (all with IE9 though).
When I load the page in IE the hover effect and FancyBox is not working. I try to refresh and toggle back and forward but nothing helps.
The I hit F12 to open the developer tools in IE to see if there are some errors. In IE you have to hit refresh to enable the script view and after a refresh everything works.

I then tested again and the same thing, if I open Dev.tools (hit F12) and refresh all works but without Dev.tools it doesn't work.
The same on all three of my Windows machines...

How come it only works in IE if I have the Dev.tools in IE opened?

This is very weird... I use "livequery" if you think that somehow could be the issue...

Comment: Check for some `Quirck mode` and `Compatibility view` issues.
What are the `Browser` and `Document` modes showing when you hit F12?
Also if any `console` functions calls like `console.log()` you might end up with error and since no console is open. But when you open it with f12 no errors are triggered.

Comment: I have console.log, yes... and removing those made it working fine in IE9 both as IE8 and IE9 comp. mode!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing console.log statements in the code solved this issue!

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction kidwon!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue yesterday, and it turns out adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />` helped me.  Apparently IE on many computers will trigger ie7 compatibility mode.